# d3.js apply rect collision in force layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js, collision-detection

There are a couple of questions regarding collision detection in force layout but with none I could solve the problem.
The closest is: [rect collision detection d3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202161/rect-collision-detection-d3js)

In the code below I do have circles but I treat them as rectangles (as that is what I want to solve in the end - bounding box of circle plus label).

Here is the code:

```
var graph = {
    "nodes":[
        {"name":"name-1","rating":1,"id":2951},
        {"name":"name-2","rating":2,"id":654654},
        {"name":"3","rating":3,"id":6546544},
        {"name":"4","rating":4,"id":68987978},
        {"name":"5","rating":5,"id":9878933},
        {"name":"6","rating":6,"id":6161},
        {"name":"7","rating":7,"id":64654},
        {"name":"8","rating":8,"id":354654},
        {"name":"9","rating":9,"id":8494},
        {"name":"10","rating":10,"id":6846874},
        {"name":"11","rating":11,"id":5487},
        {"name":"12","rating":12,"id":34},
        {"name":"13","rating":13,"id":65465465},
        {"name":"14","rating":14,"id":5443},
        {"name":"15","rating":15,"id":313514},
        {"name":"16","rating":16,"id":36543614},
        {"name":"17","rating":17,"id":3434},
        {"name":"18","rating":18,"id":97413},
        {"name":"19","rating":19,"id":97414},
        {"name":"27","rating":20,"id":9134371}
    ],
    "links":[
        {"source":0,"target":5,"value":6, "label":"publishedOn"},
        {"source":2,"target":5,"value":6, "label":"publishedOn"},
        {"source":7,"target":1,"value":4, "label":"containsKeyword"},
        {"source":8,"target":10,"value":3, "label":"containsKeyword"},
        {"source":7,"target":14,"value":4, "label":"publishedBy"},
        {"source":8,"target":15,"value":6, "label":"publishedBy"},
        {"source":9,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"depicts"},
        {"source":10,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"depicts"},
        {"source":7,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
        {"source":16,"target":2,"value":5, "label":"manageWebsite"},
        {"source":5,"target":3,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
        {"source":16,"target":4,"value":6, "label":"manageWebsite"},
        {"source":12,"target":9,"value":2, "label":"postedOn"},
        {"source":13,"target":1,"value":6, "label":"childOf"},
        {"source":10,"target":8,"value":8, "label":"describes"},
        {"source":8,"target":11,"value":6, "label":"containsKeyword"},
        {"source":2,"target":5,"value":3, "label":"manageWebsite"}
    ]
}

var width = 900;
var height = 700;
var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-500)
        .linkDistance(function(d) { return d.value * 10;})
        .gravity(0.5)
        .size([width, height]);


var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .append("g");

var rect = svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("pointer-events", "all");

var container = svg.append("g");

force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links).start();

var links = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "links")
        .selectAll(".link")
        .data(graph.links)
        .enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "link")
        .style("stroke-width", 2);

var nodes = container.append("g")
        .attr("class", "nodes")
        .selectAll(".node")
        .data(graph.nodes)
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });

var circle = nodes.append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12; })
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return color(1/d.rating);
        });

nodes.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.weight * 2+ 12 + 4; })
        .text(function(d) { return d.name });


force.on("tick", function() {
     var xnodes = force.nodes();
     var len = xnodes.length;
     var q = d3.geom.quadtree(xnodes);
     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         //does not work
         //q.visit(collideNew2(xnodes[i]));
     }

    links.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    });


    nodes.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});


function collideNew2(node) {
    var nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2, size;
    size = 250;
    nx1 = node.x;
    nx2 = nx1 + size;
    ny1 = node.y;
    ny2 = ny1 + size;
    return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        var dx, dy;
        if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
            if (overlap(node, quad.point)) {
                dx = Math.min(nx2 - quad.point.x, quad.point.x2 - nx1) / 2;
                node.x -= dx;
                quad.point.x -= dx;
                dy = Math.min(ny2 - quad.point.y, quad.point.y2 - ny1) / 2;
                node.y -= dy;
                quad.point.y += dy;
            }
        }
        return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    };
};

function overlap(n, p) {
    var nx1, nx2, ny1, ny2, size;
    size = 250;
    nx1 = n.x;
    nx2 = nx1 + size;
    ny1 = n.y;
    ny2 = ny1 + size;
    var x1 = p.x;
    var x2 = x1 + size;
    var y1 = p.y;
    var y2 = y1 + size;
    if (((x1 > nx1 && x1 < nx2) || (x2 > nx1 && x2 < nx2)) && ((y1 > ny1 && y1 < ny2) || (y2 > ny1 && y2 < ny2))) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It seems that the overlap functions as well as the selected "nodes" is wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: Could you be more specific please? How are they "wrong"? Also it doesn't seem like you're using the bounding box anywhere.

Comment: Yes, right now I try to treat the circles as rectangles (setting a fixed width and height of 250). But even that simplified version does for some reason not work. I beliefe it is the line 
var xnodes = force.nodes();
but I don't have any better idea on how to solve this.

Comment: Have you seen [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3231298)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen this example. Probably the root cause of the my problem is not the collision detection itself but more the question on what data to put in and how. E.g. in my example I would expect to put the "nodes" as parameter to the quadtree function. But that doesn't seem to work at all. So I use force.nodes(). But then I don't get any visual change on the graph.